# how to parse a value to variable using powershell from data in table format

Tags: powershell

I have command `$Var1=Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory Statement_*.pdf | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | select -First 1|Select-Object "Name"` which gives me output in below format

```
Name
----
Statement_2022MTH05_750571314.pdf
```

I only want to store `Statement_2022MTH05_750571314.pdf` file name in a variable, so that when I fire command `Write-Output $Var1` then it should print `Statement_2022MTH05_750571314.pdf` only. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-ExpandProperty Name` which will *[Specifies a property to select, and indicates that an attempt should be made to expand that property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#parameters)*. So,

```
Select-Object -First 1 | Select-Object "Name"
```

can be replaced with

```
Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Name
```